# Android how to optimize application code through Proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am working with Android sdk ver-8. (But in manifest I gave android:minSdkVersion="6")

I am developing an app. For publishing I want to optimize it. Through ProGuard how can I optimize the code?
Please give me steps of using ProGuard.

Comment: wnat "optimization" do you have in mind?

Comment: code optimization.(my apk size is 2MB i want to optimize and decrease the size of apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html):

ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so **you do not have to invoke it manually**. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode.

Comment: how to run an app in release mode?

Comment: In Eclipse's `Package Explorer` right click your project, `Android Tools` > `Export Signed Application Package...`

Answer (score 1):

See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ section "Manual" -> "Examples" -> "A complete Android application"

Comment: ya i have this link. But i m not getting how to start. Plz explain me